# Issue using Async Task

Tags: android

I am using async task in my application.I am starting a progress dialog on pre-execute and in doInBackground i'm calling a function which will return the current location from geocoder.If the current place is not available i'm showing a dialog box to manually enter the place.But it is getting crashed when the dialog comes.i'm not even able to use a toast in that function which results a force close.Can any1 have the solution for this issue..?
Please help..
This is the error that i'm getting..

```
01-03 09:45:36.216: E/AndroidRuntime(452): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-03 09:45:36.216: E/AndroidRuntime(452): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error  occured while executing doInBackground()
01-03 09:45:36.216: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
01-03 09:45:36.216: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
01-03 09:45:36.216: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
01-03 09:45:36.216: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
01-03 09:45:36.216: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-03 09:45:36.216: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-03 09:45:36.216: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-03 09:45:36.216: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-03 09:45:36.216: E/AndroidRuntime(452): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:     Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
01-03 09:45:36.216: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
01-03 09:45:36.216: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
01-03 09:45:36.216: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
```

my async task is this.

```
private class UpdateCity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait for few seconds...");
        this.dialog.setTitle("");
        this.dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) {

        checkCity(Cplacename);//my function
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {


        this.dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: You gave us no code and no stacktrace from logcat...how are we to help you?

Comment: Can you add your async task code as well, I guess you will need to call the Looper.prepare before the thread starts. As specified in the error.

Comment: I want to know how to handle the exceptions from a function which is executing in doInBackground.For example: a toast

Comment: If you are updating UI for eg. Toast, then you have to use runOnUiThread() to peform anything on the UI, you directly can't upate the UI from the worker thread. see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called
>   Looper.prepare()

From the above error in your Logcat it seems that you are trying to upate the UI from a non-UI thread. You should use `runOnUiThread()` to update your UI from a non-UI thread.

```
Activity_name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     checkCity(Cplacename);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thankz...it seems that is the problem...so where should i write the above code? in Async task?

Comment: check my edited answer, just put your method checkCity(Cplacename); inside the runOnUiThread().

Comment: If you run this code on UI thread, the complete AsyncTask is useless. I would prefer the solution from rDroid.

Comment: checkCity is not connecting to some web service, or doing some database query, is it ? if so, do not perform a heavy operation in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

THe latter part of the `logcat` referes to some `Toast` . Are you showing some `Toast` from within the `doInBackground()` function ? If some, remove that, and it should work. Do remember, `Toast` is a UI element.